# Angular Typescript access property on object with dot notation?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object `L2Language` with three properties: `short`, `long`, and `videos`. It works as expected in the child component and now I'm trying to pass the object from the child component to the parent component via an event emitter:

```html
(L2LanguageEvent)="L2LanguageEventHandler($event)"
```

The object is passing to the parent. When I view the object in the console with `console.table(L2LanguageEvent);` the properties are there:

[image]

but when I log a property on the object with `console.log(L2LanguageEvent.short);` I'm told that the property isn't on the object:

```
Property 'short' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

Here's my parent component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { L2Language } from './home-toolbar/home-toolbar.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  language: L2Language;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.language); // doesn't work
  }

  L2LanguageEventHandler(L2LanguageEvent: object) {
    console.table(L2LanguageEvent); // works, you see the result above
    console.log(L2LanguageEvent.short); // doesn't work
    console.log(L2LanguageEvent['short']); // doesn't work
    this.language = L2LanguageEvent; // doesn't work
  }
}
```

`console.log(this.language);` returns `undefined`. This suggests that the interface `L2Language` was never imported. I'm not getting the error `Cannot find module` so it's not a path problem. Or maybe it's saying the `L2Language` was imported but the property values are undefined? This is true but it shouldn't cause the error saying that the property doesn't exist on the object.

`console.log(L2LanguageEvent.short);` returns the error `Property 'short' does not exist on type 'object'.`

`console.log(L2LanguageEvent['short']);` returns two errors:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"short"' can't be used to index type '{}'.

Property 'short' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

`this.language = L2LanguageEvent;` returns the error

`Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'L2Language': short, long, videos`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: mark the `L2LanguageEvent` parameter with the type `: L2Language` instead of generic `object` and the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this part of the code

```
  L2LanguageEventHandler(L2LanguageEvent: object) { //CHANGE THIS object
    console.table(L2LanguageEvent); // works, you see the result above
    console.log(L2LanguageEvent.short); // doesn't work
    console.log(L2LanguageEvent['short']); // doesn't work
    this.language = L2LanguageEvent; // doesn't work
  }
```

Instead of object just use your interface.

```
 L2LanguageEventHandler(L2LanguageEvent: L2Language){}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd made two mistakes. First, in the child component I'd written:

```js
export interface L2Language = {
  short: string;
  long: string;
  videos: string;
};

export class HomeToolbarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() L2LanguageEvent = new EventEmitter<object>();
}
```

This is correct:

```js
export interface L2Language = {
  short: string;
  long: string;
  videos: string;
};

export class HomeToolbarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() L2LanguageEvent = new EventEmitter<L2Language>();
```

Second, in the parent component this was incorrect:

```js
L2LanguageEventHandler(L2LanguageEvent: object) {
    console.table(L2LanguageEvent);
    console.log(L2LanguageEvent.short);
  }
```

This is correct:

```js
 L2LanguageEventHandler(L2LanguageEvent: L2Language) {
    console.table(L2LanguageEvent);
    console.log(L2LanguageEvent.short);
  }
```

Rereading the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html), I see that `object` isn't a type. You make an object, give it a name, and then the type is the name. In fact, I can make my object a `type` instead of an `interface`:

```js
export type L2Language = {
  short: string;
  long: string;
  videos: string;
};
```

Note that there's an `=` in there now! The TypeScript Handbook [explains](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces) that

```
the key distinction is that a type cannot be re-opened to add new properties vs an interface which is always extendable.
```

You don't have to name an object, you can make in anonymous. That might be good for an object that it used in one function but for an object that's passed between components it should be a named `type` or `interface`.

Thanks Daniel!